# CIC filter internal register truncation

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, hardware-implementation

I try to implement CIC filter with truncation in hardware, but there is some misunderstanding. For some reason the output signal is broken.

My filter is ***N*** = 6, ***R*** = 20, ***M*** = 1, ***Bin*** = 16, ***Bout*** = 16.

(Where *N* - order, *R* - downsampling ratio, *M* - differential delay, *Bin* - input bit width, *Bout* - target output bit width)

I use [Rick Lyons article](https://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/269.php) and code for CIC stages truncation calculation. Xilinx Vivado (CIC Compiler 4.0) calculate same 'Bits per stage'.

```
 Stage(j)   Bj   Accum (adder) width
   1        1        41
   2        5        37
   3        9        33
   4       12        30
   5       15        27
   6       18        24
   7       19        23
   8       20        22
   9       21        21
  1e+01    22        20
  1e+01    22        20
  1e+01    23        19
  1e+01    26        16 (final truncation)
```

Full precision `Bin + ceil(log2((R*M)^N))` for that case is equal 42.

---

The corresponding structure, as I understand it, is below.

[image: Proposed Scheme]

But if I try filter some ***Bin*** = 16 bit sine wave, CIC output wil be incorrect.
[image: Broken signal]

For other signal level, for example 15 bit sine wave signal spectrum is fine.

For other combinations ***N*** = 6, ***R*** = 20, ***M*** = 1, ***Bin*** = 16, ***Bout*** = 19 output as well fine.

I think I'm wrong with these truncations, but don't know where.

I change one stage in truncation `set = [41 37 33 30 27 24 23 22 21 20 20 19 16]'`, i take 42 instead 41 at 1st stage, and the signal returned to normal. But is it right to do this?

Spectrum for `set = [42 37 33 30 27 24 23 22 21 20 20 19 16]'`
[image: set = [42 37 33 30 27 24 23 22 21 20 20 19 16]']

---

There is one thing - I ignore the first truncation, where the signal is immediately truncated in half. Is this my fault? Need to lose some of the information bits before filtering, why?

[image: Structure Scheme]

---

[Matlab model for first block diagram](https://github.com/alex-kis/cic_truncation_question.git)

Comment: When you create a 16 bit sine wave to test, are you sure it is scaled between -32768 and 32767?

Comment: On the last block diagram as you said, you truncate 1 bit? So if you represent your sine wave on the max amplitude in 16 bit, you remove the MSB, the sign information. You create an overflow. You could try to watch the shape of the signal after the first trunc before the first accumulator

Comment: Yes, why the first truncation?

Comment: gotchi85, yes it scaled between -32767 and 32767, like that:


`s = round(cos(2*pi * (0:2^20 - 1)' * (Fc/Fs)) * (2^(bw_s - 1) - 1));`, where `bw_s = 16` (bit width), and `Fs = 112.5e+6; Fc = 200e+3;` (sampling and carrier frequency)

Comment: I use first block diagram in model (I wonder if it is correct to use the second scheme and why the first one does not work correctly). At second block diagram I will not cut sign bit, but cut LSB, for example like that `s = round(s / 2)`

Comment: Added a model for the first block diagram for ***N*** = 6, ***R*** = 20, ***M*** = 1, ***Bin*** = 16, ***Bout*** = 16, truncation `set = [41 37 33 30 27 24 23 22 21 20 20 19 16]'`, with input sine wave ***bw_s*** = 16, and with incorrect output signal.